# Install vue.js plugin locally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a plugin that extends the `Vue` object.

```
export default {
    install(Vue, opts) {
    Vue.prototype.$tableFieldRendererTest(str){
        console.log(str);
    }
  }
```

To use this plugin I must globally install it like that:

```
Vue.use(tableFieldRenderer);

export default {
    methods: {
       test(){
          this.$tableFieldRendererTest('something');
    },
}
```

Now I want to install this plugin locally without the use of `Vue.use`, something like that:

```
export default {
    methods:{
    test(){ 
       tableField.$tableFieldRendererTest('something');
      // OR
      this.$tableFieldRendererTest('something');
    },
}
```

Comment: Your `tableFieldRenderer` is a [plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), not a component

Comment: @Phil Excellent comment! I will update the question

Comment: Given that it is a plugin, you cannot use it as a component so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `components: { tableField: tableFieldRenderer }`. You could of course alter it to also function as a component

Comment: @Phil Sure, it's just I don't know how I can use the plugin without globally installs it. I asume that Vue.use is the only way to go but I want to see if there is another way too

Comment: I think you've simplified your example too much. What does your plugin actually do in its `$tableFieldRendererTest` method? You can probably export that particular functionality separately, provided it doesn't need an actual Vue instance to operate on

Comment: I suppose that it's a stupid question since if somebody wants to use a group of functions like `tableField.$tableFieldRendererTest(..)` she could create a normal js object with these functions, no `VueJs` need it there. But is there any `VueJs` right way to do this?

Comment: @Phil Thank you for chatting with me on this, it helped me understand this a bit better. You are right, no need for vue object here, a simple class would do

Comment: While the above input is useful for the OP, the question remains still unanswered: How to  locally use a plugin?